# DB2 database directory shows DB that does not exist

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have an old test database showing when I run `db2 list database directory`

```
Database 8 entry:

 Database alias                       = TEST_AN
 Database name                        = TEST_AN
 Local database directory             = /home/users/db2inst
 Database release level               = d.00
 Comment                              =
 Directory entry type                 = Indirect
 Catalog database partition number    = 0
 Alternate server hostname            =
 Alternate server port number         =
```

But it is not there when I run `db2 list database directory on /home/users/db2inst`

I can't connect to it:

```
> db2 connect to TEST_AN
SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "TEST_AN" could not be 
found.  SQLSTATE=42705
```

or drop it:

```
> db2 drop db TEST_AN
SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "TEST_AN  " could not be 
found.  SQLSTATE=42705
```

And I can't create a new DB using that name:

```
> db2 create database TEST_AN
SQL1005N  The database alias "TEST_AN" already exists in either the local 
database directory or system database directory.
```

Does anyone know what the problem is, how can I get rid of this db that does and does not exist?

Comment: This worked.  I can now recreate a new DB with the same name.  I couldn't find the old DB on disk, so it seems the catalog was just wrong.  If you want to post this as an answer instead of a comment I will accept it.

Comment: Moved the comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would seem your local catalog is out of sync.

You may want to try `UNCATALOG DATABASE TEST_AN`, which will manually remove the database registration from the local catalog.

Answer (score 3):

for what its worth I couldn't drop a database no matter what I tried, then I figured out that if I recatalog it I could drop it.

so running

```
CATALOG DBNAME
DROP DB DBNAME
```

worked for me

Comment: Shouldn't this "CATALOG DBNAME" be "CATALOG DB DBNAME" ?

Comment: Does not work at all!